# Problem with Python server and Ajax on Firefox

Tags: python, ajax

I have a simple Python server,

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import SimpleHTTPServer

PORT = 8080

class TestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.wfile.write("ok")

def start_server():
    """Start the server."""
    server_address = ("", PORT)
    server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, TestHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

and I want to communicate with Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:8080',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data)
    }
});
```

But due to the cross-domain problem, URL = 'http://localhost:8080' doesn't work with Firefox or Chrome. My code is OK on Internet Explorer.

How can I do to resolve my pb? My HTML file is on local http://localhost/test/ and my Python server is on http://localhost:8080, and I want to communicate on the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just serve the local file via the same small Python server on another URL? This will put them both in the same domain.

If you use Apache to serve your HTML page, you can proxy ([see `ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)) your Python server so that it appears on the same domain and on the same port, just under different URL.

Comment: i have an apache server for html/ajax and a python server. How can i serve the local file via the same server ?